# How does Ruby on Rails (or ActiveRecord) remember ID's when changing an ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

First, I would like to state, I know it is bad practice to change an ID once it is set. However, I had a student ask: If you updated the ID of an existing record, would rails create a new row and leave the original row untouched, or change the ID of the existing row?

I figured we'd give it a shot and see what happened.

I changed the ID on the instance of the model, and then ran `.save` on the instance. Rails updated the original record and the SQL that was shown showed rails using the old ID in the WHERE clause, and the new ID in the actual update portion.

Where/How does Rails keep the old ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's we have some `user` with id `10` and try to change it:

```rb
user.id = 15
```

Rails track it with [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) methods:

```rb
user.changed?       # => true
user.id_changed?    # => true
user.id_was         # => 10
user.id_change      # => [10, 15]
```

If we call `user.save` and all validations will pass, SQL query will be executed like this:

```
UPDATE users SET id = 15 WHERE id = 10;
```

It will be `UPDATE`, not `INSERT` because rails know that it is existing record

Of course this will work for any columns, not only for `id`

Comment: So basically it's tracked locally as a separate parameter? My confusion is where the `id = 10` comes from since we no longer have user.id as the original 10

Comment: Yes. It's some sort of attribute of record instance

Comment: Thank you so much!! That is *incredibly* helpful

Answer (score 0):

it's not remembered. you have it until the update, in the id attribute in the database (or another one if you choose another field as a primary key), and then it's gone (unless you have something more sophisticated that logs every change).